# Replace the first line with shell command

Tags: shell, replace

My files have been attacked.

Now many of my files start with

```
; ?><?php
```

in the first line.

I want to replace it with

```
<?php
```

I need a shell command to deal with many directories in my server recursively, so the parameter can be a directory.

Only the first line is necessary, and only PHP files are necessary.

Comment: What exactly is your problem, and what have you tried to do yet?

Answer (score 1):

The command to do such an edit with sed for one file would be

```
sed -i '1s/^; ?><?php/<?php/' file
```

which replaces the file in-place. If you use BSD sed and not GNU sed, you have to specify an extension as in `sed -i.bak`.

Now, to do this for many files, you can combine the command with `find`:

```
find . -type f -name '*.php' -exec sed -i '1s/^; ?><?php/<?php/' {} \;
```

This would recursively find all `.php` files and do the replacement.

This all being said, you should probably start over from a known good backup, if you've really been hacked.

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much.
very helpful.
Actually many files are attacked in the similar way.
I placed two files here 
www.flatworld.jp/data/flatworldsoftjp/1/10/sample.zip
the function name is different but the function is the same, I think.
How to change your command to list all the files and replace it to <?php

Comment: @flatworld You might understand that I'm not going to download a zip file from a random website. If you have a new, different problem, go ahead and post a new question. It's always a good idea to show what you've already tried and how it failed.

Comment: OK, I see. Thank you again.　Any way I solved by the following command　find . -type f -name '*.php' -exec sed -i '1s/^.*<?php/<?php/' {} \;